# Postfix: Reject certain recipient addresses even though they'd be listed in the virtual alias mapsT

Tags: email, postfix, email-server, access-control-list

This will sound like a little bit of a headache, but we're moving from a Sendmail server to a Postfix server to handle mail routing on our network, selectively determining which addresses result in mail being routed to different locations (or just plain rewritten to a different @domain).  As such, the domains that are processed by this system are in the `virtual_alias_domains` list.

The problem is, we have a handful of addresses which we want to always reject, and we *also* see the addresses in the `virtual_alias_domains` catch-alls at the end of the config.  We do the following, essentially, and refer to this file in the `virtual_alias_maps` directive:

```
/etc/postfix/virtusertable:
    ...
    @domain.tld            @internal.domain.tld
```

We want to be able to do a `REJECT` with the message of "Recipient rejected by policy" along with it, so we tried to put it as follows:

```
/etc/postfix/recipient-access:
    baduser@domain.tld    REJECT Recipient rejected by policy.
    baduser@              REJECT Recipient rejected by policy.
```

and the file referred to in the config for both `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` and `smtp_relay_restrictions` with `... check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/recipient-access ...`

The problem is, we expect it to return a "Rejected" or similarly "Not permitted" response when mail destined to that target is delivered to the mail server and before it rewrites and relays to the next link in the chain.  When processed, however, by testing with `sendmail -bv baduser@domain.tld`, Postfix says the mail was deliverable (even though delivery wasn't attempted) - not 'rejected' or such.

I'm not sure where to move forward to set up such 'reject' rules.  We seem to have this 'working' over in the Sendmail system, but we want to get rid of that evil system and replace it with a Postfix system.

Note that we're trying to match the Sendmail configuration as closely as possible.  We *currently* have everything working except the rejection of certain addresses, and aren't sure how to proceed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got a solution to this, but I had to go bother the `#postfix` IRC channel on Freenode to get it.  They suggested to use `header_checks` instead to properly process the headers with regex or similar to determine rejection policies.

So, I did this.  I put into place `header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks` in the `main.cf` file for PostFix, and then set up rules like follows in the `/etc/postfix/header_checks` file:

```
/etc/postfix/header_checks:
    /^To: baduser@domain.tld/    REJECT Recipient rejected by policy.
    /^To: baduser@/              REJECT Recipient rejected by policy.
```

This could be expanded to check certain 'From' fields, or other items in the headers.  This being said, you have to know your regex a little bit to make it work.  You could use `/^From: somwhere@evildoer.tld/` for From fields or anything, but you need the `/^` part at the beginning of the regex to properly function.

It's a shame this isn't more clearly documented, but I was able to solve the issue with `header_checks`, so this counts as an answer.